# Como obtener lista de eventos a partir de la fecha actual?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

En realidad, tengo la solución, pero quiero saber si hay alguna solución mas eficiente. Lo que necesito son los eventos que aun no se han vencido por asi decirlo. Dentro de una base con todos los eventos.

Basicamente lo que hago es obtener los eventos con un OrderBy a partir de la fecha ascendentemente y luego recorro, comparando con la actual, sacando las menores. Y quedandome con las que superen la fecha actual.

Queria saber si de alguna forma, puedo desde un controlador o un composer obtener ya desde el principio la lista con la fecha que necesito, sin usar el foreach. Seria prolijo, o eficiente tambien, de alguna forma meter una consulta a la base de dato aca

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    $categorias= Categoria::orderBy('nombre','asc')->get();
    $tags= Tag::orderBy('nombre','asc')->get();
    $eventos= Evento::orderBy('fecha','asc')->get();

    foreach ($eventos as $key => $evento) {
        if ($evento->fecha <= Carbon::now()) {
             unset($eventos[$key]);
        }
    }

    $view
        ->with('categorias', $categorias)
        ->with('eventos',$eventos)
        ->with('tags',$tags);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me auto-respondo por si a alguien le sirve mas adelante.

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    $categorias= Categoria::orderBy('nombre','asc')->get();
    $tags= Tag::orderBy('nombre','asc')->get();
    //$eventos= Evento::orderBy('fecha','asc')->get();

    $eventos = Evento::where('fecha', '>=', Carbon::now())
            ->orderBy('fecha', 'asc')
            ->get();

    $view
        ->with('categorias', $categorias)
        ->with('eventos',$eventos)
        ->with('tags',$tags);
}
```

De esta forma, liberamos el foreach y ya nos trae una coleccion con los eventos con la restriccion que necesitaba